# can't send email in asp.net vb website

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, forms, contacts

When I fill in the contact form the page reloads and no mail get sent to the receiver email.

But i also want when the user presses the send button, and an email get sent to the receiver, that there a messagebox pops with text like: "a copy was sended to your email"

The ASP.NET vb code behind

```
    Imports System.Net
    Imports System.Net.Mail

Protected Sub btnSend_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Dim Message As MailMessage = New MailMessage()
        Dim Smtp As New SmtpClient()

        Dim SmtpUser As New System.Net.NetworkCredential()


        Message.From = New MailAddress("sender@domain.be", "Van voorbeeld")
        Message.To.Add(New MailAddress("receiver@domain.be", "Naar voorbeeld"))
        Message.IsBodyHtml = False



        Message.Subject = "Nefsani Contact Form"
        Message.Body = "Email: " & Qemail.Text & Environment.NewLine & "Phone: " & QTel.Text & Environment.NewLine & "Question: " & Qmessage.Text



        SmtpUser.UserName = "sender@domain.be"
        SmtpUser.Password = "Password"



        Smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = False
        Smtp.Credentials = SmtpUser
        Smtp.Host = "smtp.mijnhostingpartner.nl"
        Smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network
        Smtp.Send(Message)
    End Sub
```

code in aspx file

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 footer-widget">
                    <h4>Contacteer mij</h4>
                    <ul>                      
                        <asp:TextBox ID="QFullname" class="form-control" placeholder="Naam + Voornaam" alt="Naam + Voornaam " runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br >
                        <asp:TextBox ID="QTel" class="form-control" placeholder="Telefoonnummer" alt="Telefoonnummer" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> <br >
                        <asp:TextBox ID="Qemail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email adres" alt="Email adres" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> <br >
                    </ul>
                </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 footer-widget">
            <div class="contact-footer">
                <ul>
                    <asp:TextBox style="margin-top:52px" id="Qmessage" class="form-control" rows="4" TextMode="multiline" placeholder="Schrijf hier uw bericht." alt="Schrijf hier uw bericht." runat="server" />
                       <br><br/>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnSend" style="margin-top:-40px" class="btn btn-primary" runat="server" Text="Verzend" />
                    <asp:Label id="lblMessage" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </ul>
           </div>`enter code here`
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're getting nothing is that your button isn't tied to your click function.  You either have to add an onclick to the button or you have to add a handles event to your function.

```
  <asp:Button ID="btnSend" style="margin-top:-40px" class="btn btn-primary" runat="server" Text="Verzend" onclick="btnSend_Click" />
```

or

```
Protected Sub btnSend_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) handles btnSend.Click
```

as for displaying the message at the bottom of your click handler put:

```
lblMessage.Text = "a copy was sended to your email"
```

Comment: So i actualy just have to add onclick="btnSend_Click" and it will work?

Comment: i get a error when i use both methodes. translated to english: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not respond correctly after a certain time, or the connected connection failed because the connected host did not respond "here comes an IP" and this under it Smtp.Host = "smtp.mijnhostingpartner.nl"
Regel 35:         Smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network
Regel 36:         Smtp.Send(Message)
Regel 37:     End Sub the error is on regel 36

Comment: That error means the smtp server you are trying to use isn't allowing you to use it.

Comment: ok, thank you man for all the help, you really helped me out.